# set imagespan in the next line of text and in the center

Tags: java, android, imagespan

I want to add an image to the edit text and I am successful in adding an image. Now I want this image in the next line and in the center. I want my image to be inserted in the center of the horizontal layout and not to one side. I searched a lot of posts but could not find my answer. Here are two images what my results are now and what I want in reality.

[image]

and this I want

[image]

my code for Imagespan is

```
private void setImageinText(Bitmap myBitmap){
   myBitmap = scaleDown(myBitmap, 1360, true);
    imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
   SpannableString ssd = new SpannableString("abcde");
   d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth()/2, d.getIntrinsicHeight()/2);
   ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
   ssd.setSpan(span, 0, 5, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   texto.setTransformationMethod(null);
   texto.getText().insert(texto.getSelectionStart(), ssd);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to new spannableString for lines.

```
SpannableString ssd = new SpannableString("\n a \n");
```

and then set span

```
ssd.setSpan(span, 1 , 3, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

for the second part of the question Image in the centre, Let's wait for others to post. I am not sure how to do the other part.

Comment: Thanks for this. now image inserts in the next line. Thank you so much!. Hope so someone else post the solution for centre imagespan